# Как перемножить двумерные динамические массивы чтобы получить один?

Tags: c++

Создать 2 двумерных динамических массивов. Заполнить их рандомно числами в промежутке [-13, 13). Умножить эти две матрицы и получить одну. Вывести на экран получившуюся матрицу.

Проблема: не выводит ничего

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 13;
    int y = 13;

    int **arr1 = new int* [x];
    int **arr2 = new int* [x];
    int **arr3 = new int* [x];

    // <Присвоение>

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = new int[y];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = new int[y];
    }

    // Присвоение промежутка от -13 до 13

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            arr1[i][j] = rand() % 26 + (-13);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            arr2[i][j] = rand() % 26 + (-13);
        }
    }

    // конец

    // перемножение
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            arr3[i][j] = arr1[i][j] * arr2[i][j];
        }
    }

    // вывод

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            std::cout << arr3[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Забыли "...*Сделать самостоятельно*".

Comment: А где ваш код?..

Comment: Так у вас ведь неправильно задан диапазон значений.
`-13 + rand() % 27;`. Примерно так должно быть. А лучше использовать библиотеку `random` - Вихрь Мерсенна.

Comment: @Miracle  Вы,вероятно,  неправы с % 27, у автора обозначен полуоткрытый интервал  [-13, 13), если он ответственно подошёл к написанию скобок (хотя включение +13 выглядит симметричнее)

Comment: @MBo Странно..**Возможно** не доглядел,не прав. Старую правку вопроса нельзя ведь увидеть?

Comment: @Miracle В самой первой версии тоже `[ )` (разве что при написании вопроса в 5-минутный период могло быть по другому, те правки не запоминаются)

Comment: @MBo Тогда был не прав

Comment: @Miracle-, чтобы посмотреть старую правку вопроса, нажмите ссылку "измерен n часов назад" под вопросом.

Comment: @maestro Благодарствую

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю зачем вы по одному и тому же коду задаете разные вопросы. Меняйте тогда заголовок.

На первый вопрос, который был изначально, вам ответили: `-13 + rand() % 27`.

**Проблема: не выводит ничего** -> Вы не выделили память для `arr3`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
   arr3[i] = new int[y];
}
```